# How to know client size of browser window?

Tags: extjs

I want to know client size of browser window. I use simple script:

```
wwidth  = window.innerWidth
wheight = window.innerHeight
```

but it is not work in IE8,IE9. How to know this params using extjs in all form of browsers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a sample cross-browser function in plain javascript:

```
var getSize = function () {
    var winW = 0, winH = 0;
    if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
        winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
        winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
        winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
        winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
        winW = window.innerWidth;
        winH = window.innerHeight;
    }   
    return { width: winW, height: winH };
};

window.onload = function(){
    alert(getSize().width);
};
```

Answer (score 14):

If you're using Ext JS, you can use:

```
Ext.getBody().getViewSize()
```

Comment: `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` are not supported by IE8 or previous versions. You could instead resort to `document.documentElement.clientHeight` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight`, but since you already have the ext library, it's probably easier to use `Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height` and `Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width`.

Comment: @sra That's not what the code does. It least in Ext 4.1 there is IE browser detection where the calculation uses clientHeight and clientWidth.

Answer (score 0):

```
function viewport(){
   var e = window , a = 'inner';
   if ( !( 'innerWidth' in window ) ) {
     a = 'client';
     e = document.documentElement || document.body;
   }
   return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] }
}
```